# phpunit test passes, page load in browser fails in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, phpunit, twig

I am new to phpunit testing and did a very simple test looking for status code.

The test passes when I run:

```
bin\phpunit -c app src\AppBundle\Tests\Controller\StarLinX\TravelControllerTest.php
PHPUnit 4.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Configuration read from C:\PhpstormProjects\dir\app\phpunit.xml.dist 

.

Time: 6.03 seconds, Memory: 20.00Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

But when I load the page in the browser, an exception is thrown rendering the twig file with status code 500.

I thought maybe this was a cache issue, so I cleared cache in --env=dev, prod and test.

How do I troubleshoot this error?

This is my test file:

```
namespace AppBundle\Tests\Controller\StarLinX;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
class TravelControllerTest extends WebTestCase {
  public function testGET() {
  // Create a new client to browse the application
  $client = static::createClient();

  // get the page
  $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/travel/aaaaa');
  $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), "Unexpected HTTP status code for GET /travel/aaaaa");

  }
}
```

This is the error that is thrown when running in the dev environment:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion")
```

So after a little more analysis, I find that the error around `{{ weatherInfo }}` which should be `{{ weatherInfo.now }}`.  This throws an error when running the development environment. In production, twig simply displays `Array`.

Is that normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As it's written your test only check the error status, the test is not specific enough. What if it displayed another page? The test would still pass.

---

You should add some other tests in order to ensure that the page is properly displayed:

```
// …
$this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(),
    "Unexpected HTTP status code for GET /travel/aaaaa");

// Check that the page has a title.
$this->assertSame(
    1,
    $crawler->filter('title')->count()
);
// Check that the page has a correct title.
$this->assertSame(
    'Travel',
    $crawler->filter('title')->text()
);

// Check something in the content
$this->assertSame(
    'Hello, World!',
    $crawler->filter('body > div#content')->text()
);
```

---

If you don't have enough information to debug your code, tou can access to the page content which usually contain the error message:

```
die($this->client->getResponse()->getContent());
```

Comment: The only problem with your added tests, are that the page would still pass.  Why does twig throw an error for an array in dev but not in prod?

Comment: @ScottGutman *The only problem with your added tests, are that the page would still pass* The 2 last assertions should fail if there is an error.

Comment: @ScottGutman In prod, Twig hide errors because the debug mode is enabled (it's better to hide exceptions than *breaking* the page). But you should see the error in the log file `app/logs/prod.log`.